# Understanding how Linux syscall() works

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand what the Linux `syscall()` function expects to get. I'm looking at the `man` of the `syscall` and I can't seem to figure out the amount of parameters and what they represent. In the source code:

```
extern long int syscall (long int __sysno, ...) __THROW;
```

Does it mean that it can handle unlimited number of parameters? If not, what which parameter represents?

Comment: The number of parameters expected, and their meaning, depends on which system call you are making, i.e. the value of the `__sysno` argument.  If you're calling `_exit` (system call number 60 on x86-64), then one argument is expected, representing the exit code.  For `write` (syscall 1), three arguments, a file handle, buffer pointer, and byte count; and so on. You can pass more arguments if you want, without limit, but any that aren't expected by the system call in question will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The second arg `...` indicates a variadic function -- one that accepts a variable number of args; common examples are `printf()` and co.  By design, while the number and types of args are unknown to any variadic function, for `syscall()` the correct arg-count and types are specific to each system call, which is indexed by `__sysno` and should be a manifest constant like `SYS_exit` found in a system header.

Although the number of args is mostly unlimited, there are practical limitations, performance considerations, and arch differences; in short, fewer is often better.

Note that variadic functions can be quite versatile.  As one example: create your own (error_message + exit) variadic routine that combines an error status as the first arg followed by `printf` args; see `man stdarg` and services like vdprintf() and vfprintf().
Dual benefits include more concise source and a smaller .text segment.